# getting image src on click on image in data list

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have `datalist` containing images.

I have bounded these images to `datalist` by taking image names from database.

I just want to get `src` [Path of image] which user clicks on datalist.

My datalist is as following:

```
    <asp:DataList ID="dlImages" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4">
        <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" Height="200px" Width="200px"  runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

and i have bounded it as follows:

```
   Protected Sub dlImages_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventArgs) Handles dlImages.ItemDataBound
            If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.EditItem Then
                CType(e.Item.FindControl("ImageButton1"), ImageButton).ImageUrl = "~/ScreenMasterImages/" & e.Item.DataItem("PageName") & ".jpg"
            End If
        End Sub
```

Please help me to get src of particular image which user clicks on datasource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for this:

```
Protected Sub ImageButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs)
    Dim btn As ImageButton = sender
    Dim selImage As String = btn.ImageUrl.ToString
    MsgBox(btn.ImageUrl.ToString)
    'Shorter:
    Dim selImage As String = sender.ImageUrl.ToString
End Sub
```

Complete Code for testing:

```
Public Class WebForm1
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Dim ditems As New List(Of di)
        For i As Integer = 0 To 10
            Dim dii As New di
            dii.d_Name = "x" & i
            ditems.Add(dii)
        Next
        dlImages.DataSource = ditems
        dlImages.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub dlImages_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventArgs) Handles dlImages.ItemDataBound
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.EditItem Then
        CType(e.Item.FindControl("ImageButton1"), ImageButton).ImageUrl = "~/ScreenMasterImages/" & DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem, di).d_Name & ".jpg"
    End If
End Sub


Protected Sub ImageButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs)
    Dim btn As ImageButton = sender
    Dim selImage As String = btn.ImageUrl.ToString
    MsgBox(btn.ImageUrl.ToString)
End Sub
```

End Class

```
Public Class di

Public Property d_Name() As String
    Get
        Return m_d_Name
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_d_Name = value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_d_Name As String
```

End Class

And the asp:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlImages" runat="server" DataKeyField="d_Name" DataMember="d_Name"  RepeatColumns="4">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" Height="200px" Width="200px"  runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```